# meaning of 'Nummer' and 'jeweils' in a sentence?

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of `Nummer` and `jeweils` beneath?
I know what `Todesrad` is, but not what the `Nummer` means here. And does `mit jeweils 4 Personen` mean `with 4 persons each time`?

> Der Mitarbeiter wird mit Wirkung ab 04. März 2011 die Aufgaben von Artisten mit folgenden Tätigkeiten übernehmen: Hochseil- und Todesradnummer mit jeweils 4 Personen (gesehen wie auf dem Video bei Youtube vom 20.02.2010)

This is the [deepl](https://www.deepl.com/translator) translation  ==>

> Effective March 4, 2011, the employee will take over the tasks of artists with the following activities:  High wire and death wheel number with 4 persons each (seen as on the video on Youtube from 20.02.2010)

Comment: Beat you by 7 seconds ;)

Comment: Yeah, and I was just trying to tell you you beat me by a few seconds. So you beat me twice. <g>

Comment: Those were the 7 seconds of headstart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "-nummer" is a suffix to describe a circus act. The correct translation of

> Hochseil- und Todesradnummer

would be

> tightrope act and wheel of death act

For "jeweils", your translation already contains the right meaning.

> *Jeweils* 4 Personen

is translated as

> 4 persons *each*

This shows that both acts (the tightrope act and the wheel of death act) are performed by a group of 4 artists.

Comment: I don't think it is only used for circus acts, but rather for artistic performances in general.